# How to compose directly a tweet from my Android Application?

Tags: android

I have created on android app. i have requirement to post a tweet directly to my twitter account using my own twitter log in credentials,from my android app. i have signed up in twitter and got the consumer key and consumer secret key. With this i want my app should authorize my twitter account and i should be able to post a tweet programmatically without any pop up window. 
Regards
Kunal

Comment: I do not want any log in authorization page where user has to provide twitter credentials. all should be done programmatically.

Comment: have u check my suggested answer for your query?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a `Custom Webview` for Tweeting. It doesn't even require the Fabric Twitter API.

1 - Create a Webview Activity:

```
    public class TweetCustomWebView extends AppCompatActivity {

    android.webkit.WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            final String stringToShow = extras.getString("tweettext");
            webView = (android.webkit.WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url.contains("latest_status_id=")) {
                        // Twitted
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
                        TweetCustomWebView.this.finish();
                    }
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                public void onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
                    // Finished loading url
                }

                public void onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Log.e("", "Error: " + description);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());

                }
            });
            webView.loadUrl("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + stringToShow);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
    }}
```

2 - And a layout like this:

```
<WebView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/wv"/>
```

3 - In the `AndroidManifest.xml` we must add the activity for our `webview` inside the `<application>` tag:

```
<activity android:name=".TweetCustomWebView" />
```

4 - Last step is to call our webview when user taps Share on Twitter button:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TweetCustomWebView.class);
intent.putExtra("tweettext", "Text to tweet");
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

or you may use [Account Activity API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/overview) for **Custom Tweeting** purpose.

**That should be it. I hope this will help.**